# Checked list box Checked items Verification

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Checkedlistbox that have the following information:

```
*************
*__All Cells*
*__Cell A   *
*__Cell B   *
*__Cell C   *
*__Cell D   *
*************
```

I want to check every field that i want, however i want to if I check the "All Cells" Checkbox, all the fields have to checked automatically,  I already can do this.  The part that need help if that I want that when i uncheck the "All Cells"  checkbox all the cells are supposed to unchecked.

Here is the code that i use. Please help me with this.

```
private void Cells_CheckedListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    if (Cells_CheckedListBox.GetItemChecked(Cells_CheckedListBox.Items.IndexOf("All Cells")))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Cells_CheckedListBox.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            Cells_CheckedListBox.SetItemCheckState(i, CheckState.Checked);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: That sounds pretty unintuitive to me; if I have "All Cells," "Cell C" and "Cell D" selected and I uncheck "All Cells," I'd expect the others to remain checked... Maybe you need "select all" and "select none" buttons instead?

Comment: if have some cells selected individually, then the All Cells button is supposed to be unchecked.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be doing this in the wrong event altogether. You should handle the `ItemCheck` event.

```
private void Cells_CheckedListBox_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    int allIndex = Cells_CheckedListBox.Items.IndexOf("All Cells");
    if (e.Index == allIndex)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Cells_CheckedListBox.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i != allIndex)
                Cells_CheckedListBox.SetItemCheckState(i, e.NewValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I try this but it give me an "System.StackOverflowException'

Comment: Oh, jesus... Long day. Yeah that example wont work. I will fix it.

Comment: @HVega Fixed. Wasn't checking that we aren't setting the `CheckState` for the item that `ItemCheck` is being raised for, or we infinitely raise and handle `ItemCheck` for that item until the end of time (or a `StackOverflowException`).